# Error upon resizing

Tags: actionscript-3, debugging, resize

I'm debugging an AS3 application, when the browser window is resized I get one of two error messages:

TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at reader_fla::MainTimeline/ResetContainer() at reader_fla::MainTimeline/ResizeStage() at reader_fla::MainTimeline/StageResized()

Or:

Error: Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information. at flash.display::LoaderInfo/get width() at reader_fla::MainTimeline/GetNewLightBoxPanelSize() at reader_fla::MainTimeline/UpdateLightBox() at reader_fla::MainTimeline/ResizeStage() at reader_fla::MainTimeline/StageResized()

It's written by someone else, some time ago, spread over a LOT of .as files, and I have literally no idea what could be causing this error - if the browser is re-maximised then scaled again **no error message is shown!** I know this isn't a great deal of info to go on but if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd be very grateful.

Cheers in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be a ResizeStage function (which calls a ResetContainer function?) on the main timeline of the FLA and while calculating the resized positions, it is trying to reference an external asset that is loading.

Do you have access to the source FLA? If so, turning on the "Permit Debugging" in "Publish Settings > Flash" tab might help you to obtain the exact line of the problem.

Comment: Cheers, I'll have a look tomorrow (gone home now!) - will debugging work when in browser though? This is the real pain, I could work through it with trace functions but these don't show in browser. Thanks for your help mate.

Comment: Use the Flash content debugger plugin. http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: As @weltraumpirat said, flash debug player will show stack traces for runtime errors. It will not show trace messages though. Still, there are some sophisticated methods to allow it. Such as: http://www.thoughtlabs.com/2008/12/09/setting-up-flash-cs4-to-log-trace-messages-to-a-file/

Comment: @weltraumpirat Indeed! I forgot that it can be used to initiate remote debugging. It always came to me as a hassle though, what with the confirmation dialog when accessing the SWF with the debug player and other configuration issues I experienced. Nowadays I just use FlashDevelop's log viewer or demonster debugger.